# django 1.4 new project leads to improperlyConfigured DB ENGINE

Tags: django

I have made my searchings but found no answer. Please help!

This is what I do:

```
(holistic)chris@notebook:~/workspace$ django-admin --version
1.4
(holistic)chris@notebook:~/workspace$ django-admin startproject holistc
(holistic)chris@notebook:~/workspace$ cd holistc/
(holistic)chris@notebook:~/workspace/holistc$ vim settings.py 
(holistic)chris@notebook:~/workspace/holistc$ python manage.py startapp main
(holistic)chris@notebook:~/workspace/holistc$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/holistic/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/holistic/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/holistic/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/holistic/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/holistic/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/holistic/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/home/chris/.virtualenvs/holistic/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

and this is my `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'holistic_db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

any ideas whould be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django 1.4 the path of the settings file would be `workspace/holistc/holistc/settings.py`.

This is different from previous versions of django. You can read about the new project layout [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py).